# Orbeon Form Builder 4.4 - can database services & actions work with repeats?

Tags: orbeon, xforms, formbuilder

Say we have a form built in Form Builder that consists of one repeat, containing two controls: a text input (id) and a text output (name).  In addition we have a populated database table with two columns, `id` & `name`.

This is how the form should behave: the user can add as many rows as needed.  In each row, when an ID is entered for a row, a database service is called which looks up `name` for the given `id`, and the Name text output is populated on that row.

It's easy to get such a scheme to work if a repeat isn't involved, but with the repeat, it seems that Orbeon doesn't know from which row to get the `id` parameter value, or to set the returned `name` value.  Any options for accomplishing this that would work in Form Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is "no" for 4.4 but forthcoming v4.5 should introduce actions that work with repeats (see [here](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1105) and [here](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1527)).